# habilitar/deshabilitar un input con un select

Tags: html, vue.js, script

he visto el ejemplo en JavaScript, y si, sirve y todo pero como puedo hacerlo en vuejs, lo llevo intentando desde hace un rato y no me da. Disculpen las molestias.
Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_categoria').change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $('#d').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $('#d').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  })
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' >
    <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
    <option value="2">Empresas</option>
    <option value="3">Personas</option>
  </select>
  <input id="d" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Parece que dices que el JS mostrado funciona de forma aislada, pero no funciona cuando está integrado con otro código, pero no has mostrado ningún otro código, así que no estoy seguro de cómo podemos ayudarte. ¿Has incluido jquery.js en la página? ¿Y recibe algún mensaje de error en la consola del navegador? Además, si desea un código más corto, puede reemplazar el `if / else con $('#d').prop("disabled", this.value != "1");`

Comment: Oh bueno, lo vi en el post que ya está  resuelto, ya que básicamente quiero hacer lo mismo, pero con el framework de Vue, es exactamente lo mismo. Solo que no sé como colocarlo.

Comment: Esto se debe a que está intentando usar métodos jQuery en lugar de usar Vue. Los dos no se mezclan muy bien (es muy raro que quieras manipular directamente el DOM cuando usas Vue; generalmente dejas que el framework haga eso). Si necesitas ayuda para que este tipo de cosas funcione dentro de Vue, debes incluir tu Código de Vue en la pregunta, no solo el jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traducido del inglés, [originalmente respondido en StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844382) por [Michael Mano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6091308/michael-mano):

> Esto es una plantilla de un archivo **vue.js** que usa v-model en
> lugar de combinar jQuery
>
> ```
> <template>
>     <div>
>         <select v-model="id_categoria">
>             <option value="1" :selected="id_categoria === 1">Clientes</option>
>             <option value="2" :selected="id_categoria === 2">Empresas</option>
>             <option value="3" :selected="id_categoria === 3">Personas</option>
>         </select>
>         <input id="d" :disabled="id_categoria === 1" type="text" value="test">
>     </div>
> </template>
> <script>
> export default {
>     data() {
>         return {
>             id_categoria: 1,
>         };
>     },
> }
> </script>
> ```